# Trying to get some buttons do the same thing

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, createjs, easeljs

I am using *Animate* to create an animation. I am on the process of getting all the buttons to do what they are supposed to. Right now, I am stuck with the following. I would like to assign multiple buttons the same action, this is because the buttons appear on many different frames, so this is what I have got but I am getting an error.

```
       var btns = ["btncasco","btncasco1","btncasco2"];

       btns.forEach( btnsIteratee.bind(this)); 

 function btnsIteratee(item){
    this[item].addEventListener("click", function(event){ 
        this.gotoAndStop(0);
    });
}
```

I want to be able to click on any of the referenced button names and make them go to frame 0. Any idea about of what is wrong?

This is the error I get:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"

Comment: The first question is, why is `this[item]` undefined? Have you tried console logging out `this.btncasco`? There is a bug in animate where children aren't immediately available. Try adding `this.gotoAndStop(0)` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell from the small amount of code you have provided what else is going on that could cause unexpected behaviour of `this`. However. The following:

```
btns.forEach( btnsIteratee.bind(this));
```

Could benefit from being bound once, as the reference to `this` won't change for each instance of the forEach loop. Then having the array item passed in. Something like:

```
var btns = ["btncasco", "btncasco1", "btncasco2"];

function btnsIteratee(item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
        this.gotoAndStop(0);
    });
}

btnsIteratee = btnsIteratee.bind(this);
btns.forEach(btnsIteratee);
```

The above is pseudo code as there isn't much provided by your example

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the posts. I finally sorted this out using this chunk of code for each series of buttons.

```
var btntres = ['btnlumbrera2' , 'btnlumbrera3' ,'btnlumbrera4' ,'btnlumbrera5' ,'btnlumbrera6' ,'btnlumbrera7', 'btnlumbrera8', 'btnlumbrera9', 'btnlumbrera10', 'btnlumbrera11', 'btnlumbrera12', 'btnlumbrera13', 'btnlumbrera14', 'btnlumbrera15', 'btnlumbrera16', 'btnlumbrera17', 'btnlumbrera18']; 

btntres.forEach( btnsIteratee3.bind(this) ); 
function btnsIteratee3(item){


if (this[item] && !this[item].hasEventListener('click')) {
    this[item].addEventListener("click", hyandler.bind(this));
} else {

    console.log('item no existe', item);
}

function hyandler(event){ 
    this.gotoAndStop(4);
}
}
```